Excel VBA unable to show the file contents in my folder
I have an issue whereby when I load the file location, it would not show the content of the folder. Example when I run the code, it will show the folder being empty, but it can still load the files into the excel. It is just that the txt files couldn’t be seen. Below is part of the code that will make user select the folder and copy the txt files content to an excel sheet. My only issue is not being able to see the txt files. So, users will not be able to correctly identify if the txt files in the folder is correct or wrong. Is there any way to fix this? The first photo is what it will appear as, the second is the desired result.
      textFileLocation = GetFolderName("C:\Users\Documents\Log")
      
      fileName = Dir(textFileLocation & "\*.log") 'first text file  name
      fileDate = Format(FileDateTime(textFileLocation), "mm/dd/yyyy")
      
      If fileName <> "" Then
        Do While fileName <> "" 'loop since there still are not processed text files
            'Get File Name
            sFullFilename = Right(fileName, Len(fileName) - InStrRev(fileName, "\"))
            sFileName = Left(sFullFilename, (InStr(sFullFilename, ".") - 1))
            
            'place the content of the text file in an array (split by VbCrLf):
            arrTxt = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(textFileLocation & "\" & fileName, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
            lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'the row where to paste the array content
    
            'drop the transposed array content:
            ws.Range("A" & IIf(lastR = 1, lastR, lastR + 1)).Resize(UBound(arrTxt) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrTxt)
            
            'apply TextToColumns to whole returned data:
            ws.Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=ws.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(70, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True




The files showing .log extension but you are using *.txt extension to filter files in FileBrowserDialog. Use *.log as filter in vba code.

You're asking us to explain problems you're having with code we cannot see, which clearly does not work. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Sorry was still making changes to the post as I can only upload photos via my phone and not laptop.

@Harun24hr are you able to see the code I just updated? I believe I have used the .log extension? If I have something wrong in the code or I am missing anything in the code do help thank you.

Please, try the next adapted code:
Sub ProcessingLogFiles
  Dim textFileLocation As String, fileName As String, ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long
  Dim arrTxt as String, FullPath As String
  
  Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 'adapted to see the files:________________________________________
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Log Files", "*.log", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
             FullPath = .SelectedItems.Item(1) 'selected log file full path
        End If
  End With
  If FullPath = "" Then Exit Sub 'if Cancel pressed, the code stops
  '________________________________________________________________

  textFileLocation = Left(FullPath, InStrRev(FullPath, "\") - 1)
  fileName = Dir(textFileLocation & "\*.log") 'first log file  name
  
  If fileName <> "" Then
        Do While fileName <> "" 'loop since there still are not processed text files
            'Get File Name
            sFullFilename = Right(fileName, Len(fileName) - InStrRev(fileName, "\"))
            sFileName = Left(sFullFilename, (InStr(sFullFilename, ".") - 1))
            
            'place the content of the text file in an array (split by VbCrLf):
            arrTxt = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(textFileLocation & "\" & fileName, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
            lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'the row where to paste the array content
    
            'drop the transposed array content:
            ws.Range("A" & IIf(lastR = 1, lastR, lastR + 1)).Resize(UBound(arrTxt) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrTxt)
            
            'apply TextToColumns to whole returned data:
            ws.Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=ws.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(70, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
'....
'your existing (missing) code
'....
End Sub

You firstly, need to post the whole code. The problem was in the function you used to return the folder to be processed (not supplied). It only happens I knew what you mean from another question I answered it...

Thanks for the help, I tried it, and it works as intended where it will show the files, but when I select Log4.txt, it will copy and paste the contents from Log1.txt to Log4.txt. And not from log4.txt which I selected. Is this intended or can I make it so that it will start from where I selected. Thank you

@user23357972 I am afraid, you do not understand much of your code, no offence... In the code you show it tries extracting the FOLDER where to process All Files. Then, you use Dir to find first file in the respective folder (in alphabetical order) and after that it iterates between your existing files. What do you really want doing? To process ONLY the file you select? You did not describe ANYTHING related to what you try doing. We only deduced looking to your code and it does what I explained above... What do you understand by file location?

@user23357972 Can you clearly explain what you try doing? Even if you want starting with the selected file and then the others, it it possible, even if it does not have much of sense, I can do it. But I must understand what you need...

I just wanted to select a folder showing the content inside to ensure it is the correct folder. Then it will extract the data in the txt files to a excel sheet. The solution you gave me works as when I select the folder I am able to see the txt files, initially I can select the folder but can't see the txt files as shown in the picture. But currently when I load the txt files, it will do it by ascending order as you have said, but I want it to load the txt files by a different order.

I have made changes to the photo, if you see I have tag1_After, and tag1_Before. It inserts by Alphabetical order as you have said so it will insert the after txt file and then the before txt file, is it possible for it to insert the before first then after? Sorry for the late reply and thank you for the help

@This is something different than what you asked in your question... Excel Dir function is not able to work in this way. It simply chooses files in alphabetical order. But, it the pattern is exactly as you say ("xxx_After", "xxx_ Before") it probably, can be done, but using a complete different solution which would be not so simple. So, being something new, place a different question clearly describing what you have an what you want. If you tag me here and I will be available I will try helping. If not, somebody else will maybe solve the issue...
